# leer un archivo línea a línea en C

Tags: c

¡Hola a todos! En esta oportunidad me encuentro por aquí nuevamente debido a que estoy haciendo un programa en C que haga operaciones  con números en octal, de tipo binarias y unarias. Tengo el siguiente archivo:

### Entrada.txt

> 7 4 -
>
> 2 ~
>
> 5 4 ^

Yo necesito leer la primera línea, es decir esos tres caracteres **'7' '4' '-'**, para operar y guardar el resultado en otro archivo, y luego con la segunda línea leer **'2' '~'**, y así sucesivamente hasta el final. Mi pregunta es ¿Existe alguna manera de leer LÍNEA A LÍNEA un archivo? ya que no puedo "cablear" la cantidad de dígitos por línea de alguna forma porque habrán líneas con dos caracteres, otras con tres, etc. Lo hice de esta forma pero a modo de prueba y también para que tengan una idea del razonamiento que estoy usando:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct arrChar{
char string[9];
};

int main(){
char ifilename[]= "entrada.txt";
//~ char ofilename[]= "salida.txt";
struct arrChar aux;int i=0,j=0,res; 

FILE *ifp;
ifp=fopen(ifilename,"r");
    while (fscanf(ifp,"%s",aux.string) != EOF){
        j++;
    }
    printf("el archivo tiene %d valores",j);
fclose (ifp);     
return 0;
}
```

yo quisiera que la parte de

```
    while (fscanf(ifp,"%s",aux.string) != EOF){
        j++;
    }
```

leyera solo la linea, y estuviera anidada en un ciclo que verifique el EOF, de manera de que, por línea, pueda hacer las operaciones respectivas y guardar en archivo el resultado. Espero haberme podido explicar correctamente. ¡Espero sus opiniones!

P.D.: Mientras terminaba de escribir el post recordé que nos dieron un formato de lo que les estoy comentando, osea por línea que lees de entrada imprimes directamente el resultado en salida...

(imagen rota eliminada)

Donde B es Binario, H hexadecimal, CA2 complemento a 2, DL desplazamiento lógico, RI rotación izquierda de bits, etc.

Answer (score 2):

- fscanf(), puede no ser lo más adecuando para ciertos usos. Entonces, usaremos : `fgets()`, que es mejor para un uso más abierto. fgets() leerá hasta apurar el espacio que se le indica, o hasta encontrar un salto de linea *'\n'*.
- Es conveniente inicializar las cadenas y variables antes de usarlas, es preciso para evitar posibles errores en su ejecución. Entonces inicializaremos el array de chars de la estructura con : `*aux.string ="";`

  *Codigo comprobado ...*

---

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    struct arrChar{
    char string[9];
    };

    int main(){
    char ifilename[]= "entrada.txt";
    //~ char ofilename[]= "salida.txt";
    struct arrChar aux;int i=0,j=-1,res; *aux.string=""; char *devf;

    FILE *ifp;
    ifp=fopen(ifilename,"r");
    do
       {
        j++;
        devf = fgets(aux.string,9,ifp);
        // Aqui puedes poner código para procesar la cadena leida ..
       } while (devf!=NULL)

    printf("El archivo tiene %d valores",j);
    fclose (ifp);  

    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: genial, gracias por contestar. Esta función "feof(ifp)" nunca la había visto jeje.. Lo trataré de implementar siguiendo tus indicaciones, gracias nuevamente!!

Comment: No es buena práctica omitir revisar el valor que devuelve una función ( `fgets` en este caso) http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/

Comment: Devuelve un puntero char, si al llamar a la función el stream se encuentra en EndOfFile devuelve NULL como puntero. Gracias por indicarlo.